# Making a Network Drive Faster To Access

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba, drive

I have mounted a 450 GB Logical Volume in Ubuntu and I am sharing it over the network using Samba. On my Mac, I am able to connect to the shared folder and mount the volume; however, it takes minutes for me to see all of my files, which consist of music and photos. Is there any way to speed up this process? I know that Windows 7, for example, can index drives, but would this work even if the server is turned off and on again? My Ubuntu server is using ethernet.

Comment: Windows 7 uses indexing to _search_ files faster, this does not mean they will be displayed faster. The only way you can achieve more speed is using faster Ethernet adapters on both Ubuntu and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/samba/smb.conf on the server, check that the socket options line is:

```
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY
```

Note that adding SO_RCVBUF and SO_SNDBUF may speed things up for Linux<>Linux communication but can have some bad slowdowns for Windows or other OS that connect to the share.

As another troubleshooting step, try connecting to the share not by its name (netbios or DNS) but by its IP address (eg. 192.168.0.2).  If this works fine you have something going weird with name resolution, which is a black art (more [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch07.html)).

Comment: Yes, the socket options line is TCP_NODELAY. I tried to connect to the internal IP address of the server and it was still the same slow speed. Thank you for responding.

Comment: In that case I'm almost all out of ideas. Only other think I can think of is a firewall issue.

Comment: I don't think that would be the case; Danatela suggested to get a wired connection on all of the client computers, so I think I will try that.